# bad-tcp-flags reported for the FIN packet, that is sent immediately after 3WHS

Tags: python, linux, tcp, scapy, tcpdump

Using Scappy to craft packets, I want to terminate connection using "FIN" immediately after 3WHS but my FIN packet is not accepted by the server and I receive RST-ACK instead .

Not sure if I mess the sequence number of my FIN ...

Can someone please point out, what I could change to make it perfect ??
[image: yenter image description here]

Comment: I'd say that's exactly what you did.

Comment: Would be great , if you can help to find what could be changed to get the thing right ?